# Git - compare old commit with branches latest commit

Tags: git, commit

Background: A project I once worked on changed its licensing, and I want to know how much of my code is still in the final product.

How can I take an old commit ID and compare the changes made in that commit with the current code in any branches latest commit?

EX: I add some code

```
int b = j+k;
updateRefs(b,k);
```

and later this code gets changed to

```
int b = j+m;
updateRefs(b,k);
```

How can I see how much of my code (ex the `updateRefs(b,k);`) is still left in the latest commit of a branch?

Comment: Are you interested in a single file or multiple files? When you write "how much of my code", what measure are you actually referring to?

Comment: Maybe `git blame` and `grep` for your name?  Might help with some quick and dirty estimates.

Comment: @Jubobs interested in multiple files, although I can write a script to iterate over single files

Comment: @StephenNewell good enough for me, care to submit that as an answer?

Comment: While they can say they changed  licence, if you still have the old copy of their code, you can still use it under their original licence, unless they were in violation, see [Open Source - Am I in danger if a project component is relicensed?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1611/3408)

Comment: If you need to do this in GitHub - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838096/820410)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be rough around the edges, but you can use `git blame` and pipe that through `grep`.  For example, running on one of my projects (limiting to 10 lines since I'm the only contributor):

```
$ git blame CMakeLists.txt | grep Stephen | head -n 10
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   1) cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   2) cmake_policy(VERSION 3.9)
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   3) 
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   4) project("houseguest"
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   5)     LANGUAGES
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   6)         CXX
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   7)     VERSION
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   8)         0.1.0
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600   9) )
^72094b3 (Stephen Newell 2018-04-02 19:49:20 -0600  10)
```

This will show whoever last touched the line, so it'll miss some cases (e.g., whitespace change or comments added to the line).  Should give you at least a rough estimate though.

Comment: You can tell `git blame` to ignore whitespace changes with `-w`.