# On GitHub, how to compare between a certain commit and the current head of a branch?

Tags: git, github

On GitHub, there's a way to do a "diff" between 2 commits.
https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits

In a nutshell, it looks like this:
`https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6f`

If I wanted to compare between a certain commit in history vs. the current head of the branch, how would I do this? I don't want to always have to always look up the 7-character SHA code of the latest commit.

I've tried
`https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..head` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two different commits on the same branch in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837769/how-to-compare-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch-in-github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it the name of the branch.

`https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..master`

You can do it manually, or use the base and compare drop downs.

In general, commit IDs, branch names, and tags are interchangeable. They are all "revisions" which specify a commit. See [`gitrevisions`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for the ways you can identify commits. For example, you can compare against where `master` was two years ago.

`https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..master@{2 years ago}`

`head` did not work because the names are case-sensitive. It is `HEAD`. `HEAD` is a special reference. On your local repository `HEAD` is the currently checked out commit. On Github it will be the tip of the default branch on Github, probably `master`. If you want `master` you're better off asking for `master`.

Comment: The `@{2 years ago}` syntax only works locally and requires that your reflog contain two years' worth of updates, which is probably somewhat rare since the default expiry is 90 days. :-) (It depends of course on whether you've changed these defaults *and* whether `git gc` has run.)

Comment: @torek [Did you try it?](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..master@%7B2%20years%20ago%7D). I was a bit surprised.

Comment: Huh, interesting. This must be a GitHub feature. They have reflogs turned off (as far as I know) so they must be interpreting it some other way (probably looking at commit timestamps).

Comment: @torek I assume they have reflogs and aren't pruning them. They're cheap.

Comment: That's possible, but when you force-push, unreachable commits (which would be held by reflogs) do eventually vanish. So if they're keeping them, they've configured the expire-unreachable setting short-ish and the regular (reachable) setting to never (or years).