# Check differences between package versions

Tags: php, github, package, components, composer-php

I'm using this package "https://github.com/classic-o/nova-media-library" and it's working fine. However. I just noticed that it has a more recent version, I'm using a 0.x version but it has already a version 1.x. My doubt is if it possible to see in GitHub  the differences between both versions like what the version 1.x has extra to see if it worths the migration. Do you know if there is a way to check that?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare release tags to see changes to your repository between different releases.

See [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/comparing-releases) for more information

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837769/how-to-compare-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch-in-github) will also help